# why post_class() function apply css classes to all other files?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, themes, child-theme

I use the post_class() function to add a custom class of CSS like width and display property. But it applied to all other files like the about page, contact page. I tried to use the WordPress class instead of using the class attribute of HTML. I have referred wordpress.org. I thought post_class can use for WordPress predefined class and also for adding custom classes. It's a right or wrong method. Please suggest if anyone knows, where to use the post_class()? and it is ok to use post_class() for adding custom classes.

Comment: Have you added post id to your post_class() ? Regarding to the codex https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/ you just have to set post_class('newclass',$post_id) to have it apply to only 1 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where to use the `post_class()`

You can use it pretty much everywhere (in WordPress), e.g. single post pages (`single.php`, `single-my_cpt.php`, etc.), search results pages (`search.php`), the index template (`index.php`), a template part (e.g. `content.php`), and a shortcode function.

> it is ok to use `post_class()` for adding custom classes?

Yes, it is. [`post_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/) is not restricted to WordPress default classes only.

So for example, `post_class( 'my-class' )` will work unless if a code [filters the classes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_class/) and then removes the `my-class` from the list.

> it applied to all other files like the about page, contact page

Restricting it (your *custom* CSS class) to be applied only to certain pages is your task and WordPress won't automatically apply the restriction for you.

But WordPress provides various [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) like [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) that you can use to add a CSS class only on certain pages, hence just use the relevant conditional tag with `post_class()`.

For example, to add `my-class` only on a Page (post of the `page` type) with the slug `about`:

```html
<div <?php post_class( is_page( 'about' ) ? 'my-class' : '' ); ?>>
    your code
</div>

<!-- or maybe like so: -->
<?php
// foo-bar would always be in the list
$classes = [ 'foo-bar' ];

if ( is_page( 'about' ) ) {
    $classes[] = 'my-class';
}
?>
<div <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
    your code
</div>
```

And note that `post_class()` by default uses the current post in the current WordPress query, i.e. the post referenced to by the global `$post` variable, so if you want to output the classes for a specific post, pass the post ID (or object) to `post_class()`:

```html
// 123 (2nd parameter for post_class()) is the post ID
<div <?php post_class( 'my-custom-class', 123 ); ?>>
    your code
</div>
```